# JBoss/Angular 5+ : Not found Error (404) when trying to access <context>/<ROUTER_URL>

Tags: angular, jboss, contextpath

## Context

I have a question about my App context path configuration.
I have an Angular App that I include in a WAR (using plugin com.github.eirslett.frontend-maven-plugin) so that I can deploy it to the Jboss server of my company.

In local mode, no problem, I can access my app at http://localhost:4200/home
where /home is the route associated with my home page.
I start my application using the Angular CLI console with the command **npm run start**.

Below is an extract of my package.json.
In production mode I use the command **run buildprod**.

```
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "buildprod": "ng build --base-href=/my-app/ --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  }
```

## The problem

In production mode, I can access without http:// where CONTEXT is the name of my war, i.e my-app.war. So no problem when accessing http://HOST_NAME:4200/my-app. Then I think Angular immediately change the displayed URL to http://:4200/my-app/home.

- But, If I refresh the URL on http://HOST_NAME:4200/my-app/home (or just If I try to manually enter that URL in the address bar) I get a 404 error.

The full error message is:

> The requested URL /release-mgr/home was not found on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

## Questions

- Do you have any idea if the problem is due to any JBoss or Angular
  configuration?
- Any ideas of how to not have this error and display
  the target page instead?

Thanks a lot for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be because you have to change the tag base href = '/' to "href = '.'" in the index.html

All angular.io documentation assume that you will deploy your apps under ROOT http: // localhost: 8080 /

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a good solution.
So I post it here if it can help someone. :)

- Now I can access my application through http://HOST_NAME:8080/context-name/my-app/web/
- I can also access submenus like http://HOST_NAME:8080/context-name/my-app/web/home and no more problems when refreshing these other URIs
- I can also access web services of my JAVA application.

  - i.e http://HOST_NAME:8080/context-name/my-app/config/uris to get uris to other web services

### Angular - package.json

```js
"scripts": {
  "ng": "ng",
  "start": "ng serve",
  "build": "ng build",
  "buildprod": "ng build --base-href=/context-name/my-app/web/ --prod",
  "test": "ng test",
  "lint": "ng lint",
  "e2e": "ng e2e"
},
```

### web.xml

- Bind  Spring-dispatcher to URIs that follow the format /my-app/*

```html
 <!-- Bind Controllers on all on URI as /my-app/*. -->
 <!-- Every URI starting with /my-app/ will be handled by the spring-dispatcher-->
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/my-app/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

### Spring configuration file

- Declare static resources

```html
    <!-- Spring Resources are located in the directory /webapp/resources -->
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Static resources for the html page. -->
    <mvc:resources mapping="/web/*.css" location="/WEB-INF/angular/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/web/*.js" location="/WEB-INF/angular/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/web/*.ico" location="/WEB-INF/angular/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/web/assets/**" location="/WEB-INF/angular/assets/" />
```

### web controller

- Return index page for every possible URI in my application
  ** That way the Java application server understands all the URI bound to my controller

```html
@Controller
public class WebappController {

 @GetMapping(value = {"web","web/home", "web/tab1/list",  "web/tab1/creation", "web/tab2", "web/tab3/list"})
 public String getWebapp() {
  return "index";
 }

}
```